# XNA calling an imported exe file in project

Tags: c#, xna

I wish to call another exe while running my own project.

```
string appRoot =Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

For this I get this path : *C:\Users\Jeff TungMbp\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\menuSystemTutorial\menuSystemTutorial\ **menuSystemTutorial\bin\x86\Debug\xxxxx.exe***

This is not the bath I wish to access.

I wish to access this path : *C:\Users\Jeff TungMbp\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\menuSystemTutorial\menuSystemTutorial\ **menuSystemTutorial\xxxxxx.exe***

I don't want to do hard code like **System.Process(@"C:\xxxxxxx")** .

The reason I wish to access the path is because I've imported the .exe file into my project, the path I wish to access is the .exe exact location.

Any way to solve this problem? Or is there any other ways to make an .exe file attach with my project after publish it as setup file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Well*, I don't believe there is a way you can point directly to your `menuSystemTutorial\xxxxxx.exe` path without custom situations.

Since [`GetExecutingAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) method gets the assembly that contains the code that is **currently** executing, and Visual Studio creates your program exe under `bin\x86\Debug` folder, seems to me there is no way to do it.

But if can get the path you want from the original one, you can use [`string.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method like;

```
string appRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Replace(@"bin\x86\Debug\", "");
```